# Home Page Luma Theme Magento

Tags: css, magento

I am very new to Magento. I'm using Luma Home Page and I have a blank one
I would like to add an image that fully stretch out to cover the entire browser viewport. 
Can I do that from the admin panel
Tweaking the following CSS inside home page content?

```
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/qualytaly/home-main.jpg"}}" width="1280" height="460" /></p>
```

if not what would be the procedure to be followed?

Thanks

Comment: did you try width: 100%; height: auto;

Comment: Yes, I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: you want to stretch that over header and footer too ?

Comment: Simply stretch it for screen's full width

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check parent div properties. If parent div has some fixed width then your image will not go in full width even with 100% width.